# SDWebImageView Cache issue when offline and with percent escaped URLs

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage, nsurlcache

I am using `SDWebImage` to display images asynchronously, and cache them, then to get them when in offline mode.

I am having an issue with `SDWebImageDownloader` and `UIImageView+WebCache` Cache when using offline mode, and that issue appears only when dealing with percent escaped URLs, that have some special characters like '{'.

In online mode all works fine, but in offline mode the images with URLs containing percent escapes are not loaded

```
[myImageView setImageWithURL:[urlImage percentEscapedURL]
                   completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                       //image here is loaded in offline mode only if its URL does not need percent escapes
                   }];
```

The same issue with `SDWebImageDownloader`.

I tried to debug `SDImageView` behaviour, and it seems that it's using the iOS SDK `NSCachedURLResponse` behaviour.

I am testing with https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/ with iOS 7.0

Any one has got the same issue? any workaround?

Comment: What is `percentEscapedURL`?

Comment: @SergeyNikitin It's my NSString category, to get a percent escaped URL only if needed : 

-(NSURL *) percentEscapedURL {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self];

    if (url == nil) {
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    return url;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDWebImage has some property declared in `SDWebImageManager.h`:

```
@property (strong) NSString *(^cacheKeyFilter)(NSURL *url);
```

There are the description of this property from corresponding file:

```
/**
 * The cache filter is a block used each time SDWebImageManager need to convert an URL into a cache key. This can
 * be used to remove dynamic part of an image URL.
 *
 * The following example sets a filter in the application delegate that will remove any query-string from the
 * URL before to use it as a cache key:
 *
 * @code

[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] setCacheKeyFilter:^(NSURL *url) {
    url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:url.scheme host:url.host path:url.path];
    return [url absoluteString];
}];

 * @endcode
 */
```

I think you can try to do some changes in corresponding code.